# laravel I'm trying to get substract value in view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

hello im trying to get substract value in controller to pass in view using two different table.

**im getting error**

```
ErrorException
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number
```

**my table**

```
table_a and table_b

table_a columns selected "price"     //discount $100 is percent in table_a
table_b columns selected "discount"  //discount $5 is percent in table_b
```

**my controller**

```
   public function index()   
   {
 
        $table_a = TABLE_A::get(['price']);
        $table_b = TABLE_B::get(['discount']);
 

 $substract = $table_a - $table_b ; 

       return view('Home', compact('substract' ));
    
   }
```

**view**

```
<b> final value </b>
<h1> {{ $substract}}</h1> //value need to get $95
```

Comment: have you tried `dd($substract)`? Your method in controller looks suspicious. Please write real code that you've.

Comment: You need to use `first()` method, because `$table_a` and `$table_b` are returning `collection`, so do `TABLE_A::first(['price']);`

Comment: @shyammakwana.me i tried first but it getting error Object of class App\TABLE_A could not be converted to number

Comment: @shyammakwana.me without using $substract = $table_a - $table_b ;  iam able to get  in view like this {"price":"100"} {"discount":"5"}

Comment: what you're printing in view if not `$substract`?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me i used $substract in view error Object of class App\TABLE_A could not be converted to number it showing error to this line  $substract = $table_a - $table_b ;

Answer (score 1):

You must understand some basic Laravel to see that you are doing a wrong thing.

1. `Model::get()` returns a Collection (that may or not have items)
2. A collection acts like an extended array (i.e it's an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection), it has many methods to help you handle data such as `contains`,`find`, `map`, `filter`, etc.
3. Each item in the collection is an Model, not an number directly.
4. You cannot sum/subtract an array directly.
5. Also you cannot sum/subtract Model obejcts directly.

That said, you have a few conception problems:

1. To make the subtraction, you need to choose a row and a column first, eg: `Table_A::first()->price - Table_B::first()->discount`
2. The code in 1. will not work as you expect unless you have a single row in your tables.

Comment: thank you for reply can you help me to integrate your code in my code

Comment: @Elias Soares post your answer code

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information. Explain what are you trying to archive

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is odd, but this should work to fix your code.

```php
public function index()   
   {
 
        $table_a = TABLE_A::first();
        $table_b = TABLE_B::first();
 

 $substract = $table_a->price - $table_b->discount ; 

       return view('Home', compact('substract' ));
    
   }
```

If you want instead to sum all values in every table you can do

```php
public function index()   
   {
 
        $table_a = TABLE_A::sum('price');
        $table_b = TABLE_B::sum('discount');
 

 $substract = $table_a - $table_b ; 

       return view('Home', compact('substract' ));
    
   }
```